# Query and use dynamic/anonymous object from Dapper in VB.Net

Tags: .net, vb.net, dynamic, dapper

I have a query in which I perform complex calculations, including NULL handling and special cases for division by 0. This is a simplified example, provided only as a context for the problem :

```sql
SELECT
    CASE
        WHEN SUM(f.AmountA) > 0 AND SUM(f.AmountB) > 0 THEN --Perform calculations...
        WHEN SUM(f.AmountB) < 0 THEN --Perform calculations...
        WHEN SUM(f.AmountB) = 0 THEN --Perform calculations...
    END AS Result
FROM Foo f
JOIN Bar b ON b.BarID = f.BarID
```

To improve maintainability and readability, I would like to leave the calculations to be performed by .Net code. The query would be similar to this example :

```sql
SELECT SUM(f.AmountA) AS SumA, SUM(b.AmountB) AS SumB
FROM Foo f
JOIN Bar b ON b.BarID = f.BarID
```

Then, I would need to query those fields (with Dapper), which are not defined in a specific POCO. In C#, I could do something similar to what's done in [this answer and its comments](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6161472/2699889). However, in VB.Net with `Option Strict On`, I'm not able to do any of this.

To better describe what I'm trying to do, this is what it *could* look like, if it wasn't of the error `Option Strict On disallows late binding` on `u.SumA` and `u.SumB` within the `New With` statement. Note that I set `Option Infer On` at the top of my class :

```vb
Using connection As New SqlClient.SqlConnection(myConnectionString)

    Dim result = connection.Query(myQuery).Select(Function(u) New With {.SumA = u.SumA, .SumB = u.SumB}).FirstOrDefault()

    If result.SumA > 0 AndAlso result.SumB > 0 Then
        'Perform calculations...
    End If
    'Other cases...

End Using
```

This probably has to do with the lack of the `dynamic` type in VB. Therefore, the non-generic `Query` override returns an `IEnumerable(Of Object)` instead of its C# counterpart, `IEnumerable<dynamic>`.

My question is: Is there a way to do what I want to do with Dapper and VB.Net?

Answer (score 0):

I just wrote a simple (private/inner) data class, which has all the properties you need to map. I know it's sad, but thats vb.net...