# How to return List<dynamic> with Dapper.NET ORM that can bindable?

Tags: c#, .net, dynamic, reflection, dapper

**This question is old now, Dapper data-view binding are fixed** as shown answer below :)

**Hello,** Dapper ORM is very fast and light-weight database mapper. so people use it as a replace of slowly entity framework or old plain ADO.NET.

I asked this question and answer it, many developers really carious about return a real-time List from Dapper.NET ORM that can bindable to grid. rather than current repository that only returns `List<DapperRow>` which is useless for binding things.

Problems of current Dapper.NET repository **( Speaking about dynamic things )**

1. `List<dynamic> dynamicList = IConn.Query(queryString);` returns `DapperRow`
2. The `List<DapperRow>` is useless for those who know dynamic things specially who cares about filling GridViews & TreeLists
3. Library itself is hand or wanna say hard-coded one. contains list of OPCodes ( MSIL injections ) so many developers feel a pain when need to enhance or develop customization dynamic things.

After taking much time on this things. and with some helpful from other contributors. I created this class file that help developers to binding dynamically with high performance. **SqlMapper.Dynamics.cs** as shown below.

Actually the effecient and speed of dynamics is give very high performance over strongly typed list.

`List<dynamic>` Dapper ORM with **SqlMapper.Dynamics.cs** **Hit 55 - 65 ms**

`List<StronglyTypedClass>` Hit 72 - 73 ms

6,000 Records test with Intel Xeon
[image: 6,000 Records test with Intel Xeon]

**SqlMapper.Dynamics.cs**  [Link Here](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1ltAQGfszE5SgCdr5hZU0r1Z8wfiq3nQT)

**Usage :**

1. You must use this unit / class with current Dapper repository source code [Github Link](https://github.com/StackExchange/Dapper)
2. Compile your repository with **SqlMapper.Dynamics.cs**, add file to Dapper folder.
3. Then just use the new extension-method `QueryDynamic(string yourQuery)`

   ```
    IDbConnection db = new SqlConnection("server=(local); database = test");
    string query = "SELECT * FROM Table";
    dynamic BindingList = db.QueryDynamic(query);

    gridControl1.DataSource = BindingList;   // For WinForms Grids

    gridControl1.ItemsSource = BindingList;  // For WPF Grids
   ```

Please, don't modify this question.
As i just help developers who use Dapper.NET ORM library with Dynamic bindings things ( GridViews, TreeLists, etc.. )

Comment: Unfortunately, this is actually considered off-topic for this site, as it is intended to be used in a "question and answer" format. I realize that you want to make this available for future people searching for this. A better fit might be https://codereview.stackexchange.com/, or, perhaps you can find another way to format this such that it fits into the Q&A format that is used on this site, perhaps by proposing it as a question, then creating an answer (and letting others add their own answers).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've added `TypeDescriptor`-based bindings to `DapperRow`, which means that anything obtained via `Query()` (the `dynamic` API) should now bind to much common UI controls. Anything from [1.60.5](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Dapper/1.60.5) or above should work.

Let me know!

Caveat: it *doesn't* currently work for empty results (zero rows). I know how to implement that (see [notes here](https://github.com/StackExchange/Dapper/blob/3bf2b4f703fde8ee150b8ecf5ea32c14c9ce78da/Dapper/SqlMapper.DapperRow.Descriptor.cs#L21-L35)), but that would require some additional changes to the query implementation that I have not done as-yet.