# How do I loop through Dapper dynamic query results using strings as parameters?

Tags: c#, dynamic, dapper

So I came across this code:

```
dynamic account = conn.Query<dynamic>(@"
                SELECT Name, Address, Country
                FROM Account
        WHERE Id = @Id", new { Id = Id }).FirstOrDefault();
Console.WriteLine(account.Name);
Console.WriteLine(account.Address);
Console.WriteLine(account.Country);
```

([How to return dynamic types List<dynamic> with Dapper ORM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26659819/how-to-return-dynamic-types-listdynamic-with-dapper-orm)).

I was wondering how I could do the same using strings as parameters. Kinda like so:

```
dynamic account = conn.Query<dynamic>($@"
                SELECT {commaseperated(parameters)}
                FROM Account
        WHERE Id = @Id", new { Id = Id }).FirstOrDefault();
Console.WriteLine(account[parameters[0]]);
Console.WriteLine(account[parameters[1]]);
```

Where parameters is of type string[]. All results are of type string, so using dynamic may not even be necessary.

Comment: `so using dynamic may not even be necessary` bingo! There's no need to pull in dynamic types for this simple use case.

Comment: So how do I loop through the results using the string parameters?
If I loop through the query results I only get the first parameter, like so:
var res = connection.Query<string>(@$"SELECT {parameters.addCommas()} FROM...");
foreach(string s in res)
                    {
                      //s is just the first column/parameter
                    }

Comment: Try `connection.Query<IEnumerable<string>>(...)`

Answer (score 0):

I assume you could do something like this:

```
        string[] parameters = new string[] { "param1", "param2" };

        dynamic account = conn.Query<dynamic>($@"SELECT {String.Join(",", parameters)} FROM Account WHERE Id = @Id", new { Id }).FirstOrDefault();

        foreach (string s in parameters)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(account.GetType().GetProperty(s).GetValue(account, null));
        }

        Console.ReadLine();
```

Comment: I can't call GetType() on a dynamic. I'm not querying any kind of object, just random strings from random columns