# How to use generic and Nullable<T> types in Dapper for materialization?

Tags: c#, generics, tuples, nullable, dapper

I have this call:

```
public IObservable<T> Subscribe(object topic, string service, string connectionString, string query)
{
    try
    {
        this.connection.ConnectionString = connectionString;
        this.connection.Open();
        this.connection.Query<T>(query, new { transactionid = topic }).ToObservable().Subscribe(message => this.subject.OnNext(message));
        return this.subject;
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        this.subject.OnError(e);
        return this.subject;
    }
    finally
    {
        this.subject.OnCompleted();
        this.connection.Close();
    }
}
```

This is my query:

```
with IDS as  (select L1_ID, L2_ID, L1_VALUE, L2_VALUE 
from MYDB where MYDB.ID = :transactionid) 
select * from 
(select L1_ID as ID, round(L1_VALUE, 28) as VALUE from IDS
union 
select L2_ID as ID, round(L2_VALUE, 28) as VALUE from IDS) UN
```

This throw this error:

> A parameterless default constructor or one matching signature
>   (System.String ID, System.Decimal VALUE) is required for
>   System.Tuple`2[[System.String, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0,
>   Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089],[System.Nullable`1[[System.Decimal,
>   mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]], mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0,
>   Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]] materialization

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem here isn't the `Nullable<T>`, it is the `Tuple<,>`.

Dapper assumes one of two patterns. Let's assume our data has columns

```
ID      varchar
VALUE   decimal
```

(since that seems to be the case in your scenario)

To load that into a `T`, it wants to do *either* (after it has determined that `0` is `ID` and `1` is `VALUE`, etc):

```
T row = new T() { ID = reader.GetInt32(0), VALUE = reader.GetDecimal(1) };
```

*or*

```
T row = new T(ID: reader.GetInt32(0), VALUE: reader.GetDecimal(1));
```

note that I'm simplifying a lot of stuff here, and it is fairly forgiving about case sensitivity, but that's *basically* what it wants.

Now, the problem is: `Tuple<T1,T2>` *doesn't have either of those*. It has the constructor:

```
public Tuple(T1 item1, T2 item2);
```

which *won't work here* - dapper can't be absolutely sure what is meant to go where, so it *doesn't try*. This sounds harsh, but dapper tries not to mind about column order, and *in the general case* (where the columns aren't all different types), it is not clear what the correct approach should be when there is no match.

Options:

1. create a custom type of the form:

   ```
   public class SomeType { // could also be a struct, immutable, whatever
       public int Id {get;set;}
       public decimal Value {get;set;}
   }
   ```

   and use `T` === `SomeType`
2. use the non-generic API and re-map:

   ```
   Query(query, new { transactionid = topic }).Select(
       row => Tuple.Create((int)row.ID, (decimal)row.VALUE
   ).Whatever(...);
   ```
3. name your result columns `item1` and `item2` (yeuch!)

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. I settled on using KeyValuePair<> and naming my columns "as KEY" and "as VALUE".

Comment: This answer in another related question is using ValueTuple struct and it seems work: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6147121/dapper-and-anonymous-types/71400985#71400985