# Returning an anonymous type when using context.Object.SqlQuery

Tags: c#, sql, linq, entity-framework

Lets say I want to select the first product returned in a category, but I need to do it passing a sql string directly. Notice how I am specifying context.Products.SqlQuery. I thought this would work even if I don't select all of the product fields in my query. Do I really have to select an anonymous type and then convert it to a product?

**The error I am getting is:**
*The data reader is incompatible with the specified 'AppModel.Product'. A member of the type, 'InsertDate', does not have a corresponding column in the data reader with the same name.*

**Below is my code:**

```
StringBuilder sql = new StringBuilder();

sql.AppendLine("SELECT Id, ProductName ");
sql.AppendLine("FROM Product ");
sql.AppendLine("WHERE CategoryId=@CategoryId ");
var retval = context.Products.SqlQuery(sql.ToString(),
         new SqlParameter("@CategoryId", categoryId)).FirstOrDefault();

return retval;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Entity Framework can't construct the whole Product object from the results of your SQL statement because you're only returning those two fields. It should work if you did:

```
sql.AppendLine("Select * ");
sql.AppendLine("FROM Product ");
...
```

or if you specified all of the fields manually.

Comment: What are my alternatives if I do not want to select more than those 2 fields in this particular query? I would assume I can somehow select into an anonymous type then create a new Product and populate just those 2 fields from the anonymous type correct? If so do you know how I would do that? I think it is something like context.Database.SqlQuery<>(

Comment: @JTunney EF does not support that functionality, if you want that you need to switch to a library that revolves more around passing the queries in manually. For example [dapper can do it](http://stackoverflow.com/a/30469302/80274)

Comment: Thank you for the straight forward response. This is going to suck because I am converting the DAL in an old app to the DAL in a new app that uses entity framework. I am converting most of the functions to use linq but there are some functions with huge strings as SQL Queries that I don't have time to convert right now. I guess my only option is to select * since I can't not use EF.

Comment: Seems like one possible alternative is to use stored procs which return a complex type that I can then transfer to my product entity.

Comment: Instead using select * you can write all fields but with default values, for example:
select Id, ProductName, null as FullName, null as Address, etc.