# Cannot apply indexing with [] to an expression of type 'object' with AsEnumerable()

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, linq, dapper

I get the following exception :

> Cannot apply indexing with [] to an expression of type 'object'

I don't know what's the alternative to `AsEnumerable()` method in my case .

```
resultList = conn.Query(query.ToString(),
               new
               {
                  years = new[] {year, year - 1, year - 2},
                  yearsLimit = new[]
                  {
                     year,
                     year - 1
                  },
                  PeriodTypeId = periodTypeId,
                  Period = period
               }).AsEnumerable().
            GroupBy(r => r["CompanyId"]).Select(c => new //ERROR
            {
               Company = c.Key,
               Totals = c.Select(t => new
               {
                  Total1 = c.Select(t1 => new {Year = t1["Year"], Total1 = t1["Tot1"]}).ToArray(),
                  Total2 = c.Select(t2 => new {Year = t2["Year"], Total2 = t2["Tot2"]}).ToArray(),
                  Total3 = c.Select(t3 => new {Year = t3["Year"], Total3 = t3["Tot3"]}).ToArray(),

               }).FirstOrDefault()

            }).ToList();
```

Comment: What's the return type of `Query`?

Comment: @KMoussa :`IEnumerable<object>`

Comment: I'm not sure what type is returned by `conn.Query()`.

Comment: @DanWilson it's returned from dapper as `anonymous`

Comment: @AnynameDonotcare so why do u need to call `AsEnumerable` again? Also, I assume in runtime `Query` returns an `IEnumerable` of some other type?

Comment: Also, you have a generic version of `Query` right?

Comment: @KMoussa interesting point , but this'snot the problem

Comment: @KMoussa :what do you mean by generic version ?

Comment: It is `IEnumerable<dynamic>` https://github.com/StackExchange/dapper-dot-net/blob/91725fb309a9e5948f760fac420dd805659f0749/Dapper/SqlMapper.cs#L615 The comments say you can cast it to `IDictionary<String, Object>`, so a `Cast<IDictionary<String, Object>>()` before the `GroupBy()` should work according to the documentation.

Comment: I mean `Query<T>` where you can specify the return type. Also check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6147121/dapper-and-anonymous-types .. I assume you can do `.OfType<IDictionary<string, object>>` instead of `AsEnumerable` then

Comment: @KMoussa Thanks a lot ,it works the way you explain , Could you post an answer with more documented info to accept it as an answer to the question .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per Dapper's [Documentation](https://github.com/StackExchange/dapper-dot-net), and as @Technetium noted in the comments, the non-generic version of the `Query` method retuns `IEnumerable<dynamic>`

One way to get your code working is to replace `.AsEnumerable` with `.OfType<IDictionary<string, object>>` (according to [this](https://github.com/StackExchange/dapper-dot-net/blob/91725fb309a9e5948f760fac420dd805659f0749/Dapper/SqlMapper.cs#L615) and [that](https://github.com/StackExchange/dapper-dot-net/blob/61e965eed900355e0dbd27771d6469248d798293/Dapper/SqlMapper.DapperRow.cs) code, it appears that `Query` actually returns `IEnumerable<DapperRow>`, and `DapperRow` inherits from `IDictionary<string, object>`), otherwise you can access the properties directly on the returned `dynamic` (e.g. r.CompanyId vs r["CompanyId"])

Also, [here is](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6147121/dapper-and-anonymous-types) an answer to a similar question on SO, for reference.