# Is there any .net ORM that doesn't need classes?

Tags: c#, .net, orm

Is there something like this in .net?
https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/queries

```
//sample query
var users = DB::table('users')->select('name', 'email as user_email')->get();
```

And since this ORM doesn't need classes, I'm thinking it should return a `List<Dictionary<string,object>>` instead of `List<User>` where I can access the values via:

```
foreach(var user in users){
    //something like this
    Console.WriteLine("my name is "+user["name"]);
}
```

Comment: You can do this with Dapper for example (see this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/6161472/5311735).

Comment: @Bas but EF needs me to define classes. Most of my tables have more than 100 columns

Comment: Use PetaPOCO or Dapper, these are micro ORM which can fulfill your requirements.