# How do I execute a raw SQL query to a custom object in Entity Framework Core 3.1, without migrations wanting to create a table?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I'm querying a `Store` table to show the user the 10 closest `Store`s. I'd like to display the `Name` and `Distance` of the `Store`, but prefer to keep distance in a custom entity.

`Store` fields: `Id`, `Name`, `Latitude`, `Longitude`, etc
`StoreDto` fields: `Id,`Name`,`Distance`

[This SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50452479/13700) gets us on the right track, particularly with the comments. However, DbQuery is now deprecated.

The docs on [Keyless Entity Types](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/keyless-entity-types) say we can use a Keyless Entity Type to serve as the return type for raw SQL queries.

My DbContext already has:

```
public DbSet<Store> Stores { get; set; }
```

Adding

```
public DbSet<StoreDto> StoreDtos { get; set; }
```

And

```
modelBuilder.Entity<QuestSiteDto>()
    .HasNoKey()
    .ToView(null); // Hack to prevent table generation
```

Allows my store search code to work. But the next time I run a migration, EF Core wants to create a StoreDto table, unless I add that ugly `ToView(null)` hack.

For reference, here is my query:

```
var sql = 
@"select 
    geography::Point({0}, {1}, 4326).STDistance(geography::Point(Latitude, Longitude, 4326)) / 1609.34 as Distance,
    Id,
    [Name]
from
    Store"

var results = await StoreDtos
    .FromSqlRaw(sql, latitudeUnsafe, longitudeUnsafe)
    .OrderBy(x => x.Distance)
    .Take(10)
    .ToListAsync();
```

What is the proper way to do this? If you believe you know the recommended way, can you please cite your source? As of the time of this posting, the Keyless Entity Types doc page focuses more on Views and Tables rather than raw queries (unless I missed something).

Comment: DbQuery<T> is deprecated.

Comment: Indeed, I could reproduce the same issue. Currently, as a walkaround, I comment the CreateTable in the first Migration file manually to avoid creating a table.

Comment: Just use NotMapped attribute in the Dto Class

Comment: EF is major garbage! I dont understand how this flaw still not fixed till this day!

Answer (score 10):

You can also query types not registered in your DbContext.  The idea is to introduce introduce a separate single-entity DbContext type for each ad-hoc query type. Each would be initialized and cached seperately.

So just add an extension method like this:

```
   public static class SqlQueryExtensions
    {
        public static IList<T> SqlQuery<T>(this DbContext db, Func<T> targetType, string sql, params object[] parameters) where T : class
        {
            return SqlQuery<T>(db, sql, parameters);
        }
        public static IList<T> SqlQuery<T>(this DbContext db, string sql, params object[] parameters) where T : class
        {

            using (var db2 = new ContextForQueryType<T>(db.Database.GetDbConnection()))
            {
                return db2.Query<T>().FromSql(sql, parameters).ToList();
            }
        }


        class ContextForQueryType<T> : DbContext where T : class
        {
            DbConnection con;

            public ContextForQueryType(DbConnection con)
            {
                this.con = con;
            }
            protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
            {
                //switch on the connection type name to enable support multiple providers
                //var name = con.GetType().Name;

                optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer(con);

                base.OnConfiguring(optionsBuilder);
            }
            protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
            {
                var t = modelBuilder.Query<T>();

                //to support anonymous types, configure entity properties for read-only properties
                foreach (var prop in typeof(T).GetProperties(BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public ))
                {
                    if (!prop.CustomAttributes.Any(a => a.AttributeType == typeof(NotMappedAttribute)))
                    {
                        t.Property(prop.Name);
                    }
                    
                }
                base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
            }
        }

    }
```

Or for EF Core 5:

```
public static class SqlQueryExtensions
{
    public static IList<T> SqlQuery<T>(this DbContext db, Func<T> targetType, string sql, params object[] parameters) where T : class
    {
        return SqlQuery<T>(db, sql, parameters);
    }
    public static IList<T> SqlQuery<T>(this DbContext db, string sql, params object[] parameters) where T : class
    {

        using (var db2 = new ContextForQueryType<T>(db.Database.GetDbConnection()))
        {
            return db2.Set<T>().FromSqlRaw(sql, parameters).ToList();
        }
    }


    class ContextForQueryType<T> : DbContext where T : class
    {
        DbConnection con;

        public ContextForQueryType(DbConnection con)
        {
            this.con = con;
        }
        protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
        {
            //switch on the connection type name to enable support multiple providers
            //var name = con.GetType().Name;

            optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer(con);

            base.OnConfiguring(optionsBuilder);
        }
        protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            var t = modelBuilder.Entity<T>().HasNoKey();

            //to support anonymous types, configure entity properties for read-only properties
            foreach (var prop in typeof(T).GetProperties(BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public))
            {
                if (!prop.CustomAttributes.Any(a => a.AttributeType == typeof(NotMappedAttribute)))
                {
                    t.Property(prop.Name);
                }

            }
            base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
        }
    }

}
```

Use would look like:

```
using (var db = new Db())
{
    var results = db.SqlQuery<ArbitraryType>("select 1 id, 'joe' name");
    //or with an anonymous type like this
    var results2 = db.SqlQuery(() => new { id =1, name=""},"select 1 id, 'joe' name");
}
```

This originally appeared here, but github issue comment threads aren't very discoverable: https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/issues/1862#issuecomment-451671168

Comment: Creating a context for each DTO seems like a major hack. Is there really no proper, official support after 3 years? I do appreciate you trying to help, though.

Comment: Yes, a hack.  But DbContext metadata is cached by EF to reduce DbContext startup time.

Comment: Ha, I'd deleted my comment and made a new updated answer, only to see that you did an update at the same time, which pretty closely matched my answer.  So... I deleted my answer.  All in a day's work!

Comment: Try using dapper: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6147121/dapper-and-anonymous-types, and the dapper required instance of IDbConnection from ADO.NET can get from EF Core through `DbContext.Database.GetDbConnection()`

Answer (score 9):

To create the equivalent of DbQuery in ef core 3.x you add HasNoKey() and ToView() to your Entity in your modelcreating. This will prevent Migrations from creating a table.

```
public DbSet<Store> Stores { get; set; }
public DbSet<StoreDto> StoreDtos { get; set; }

protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Entity<StoreDtos>(sd =>
    {
        sd.HasNoKey().ToView(null);
    });
}
```

Comment: It still tries to create the table.

Comment: sd.ToView(...) will prevent table creation, though I believe the API will be changed in future.

Comment: Jeremy is correct, I updated the answere accordingly

Comment: @Johan just out of interest is there away to do this without having to make the modelBuilder aware of your type....just seems like a backwards way of going with regards to the direction EF team took, if you are forced to make the "context" aware of types, which well it doesn't really need to know about if you are not using any context operations on.

Comment: @Seabizkit As far as I know the only way to execute raw sql is to add the entity to the context and use FromSqlRaw/FromSqlInterpolated. And I agree it feels more complicated in 3.x compared to 2.x.

Comment: I found the ToView(null) hack in [this github thread](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFrameworkCore/issues/18719) but I can't believe we still have to do hacks on version 3.1 on this product. There must be a proper way, right?

Comment: For the record, user thienn details a [migrations-based workaround on this github thread](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFrameworkCore/issues/2725#issuecomment-286709239).

Answer (score 0):

One solution I got to maintain all dtos in the database was to create a view
with a dummy return type.

**The view**

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW public.result_function_metrics
AS SELECT 0::double precision AS date_year,
    0::double precision AS date_month,
    0::bigint AS metric,
```

**The function**

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION fx_reports_goals (
    _user_id int8, 
    _date_from timestamp with time zone, 
    _date_to timestamp with time ZONE
)
RETURNS SETOF result_function_metrics
AS 
$$
BEGIN

... 

END
$$
LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

```cs
var query = @"SELECT * FROM fx_reports_goals(
            @pUserId,
            @pDateFrom,
            @pDateTo);";
      var parameters = new NpgsqlParameter[3];

parameters[0] = new NpgsqlParameter("pUserId", NpgsqlTypes.NpgsqlDbType.Bigint);
parameters[0].Value = filter.userID ?? (object)DBNull.Value;
--- 
// same for the rest of params
--- 

var results = await db.ResultFunctionMetric.FromSqlRaw(query, parameters).ToListAsync();
```

Notice that db contains the dbSet `ResultFunctionMetric` scaffolded from the empty view.

TL/DR
It is easier to set return type from the function or stored procedure add a dummy view with the expected return values and as a bonus you still get that everytime you scaffold (database first approach)